# Why can't I comment on nominations?

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

On the [Stack Overflow election](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1), I am allowed to post comments under the various nomination posts.  When I try on the [restarted Japanese election](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1), all I see is:

> comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews

Is this an artifact of restarting the election or is the Stack Overflow election special and comments aren't normally allowed on nominations?

Comment: I do not remember if we could comment on the first election, since all the nominations came in so late in the cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifact of the reboot; Geoff has unlocked them. Please let me know if you encounter further difficulties.